# Which is the "correct" content-type for FLAC?

Tags: mime-types, flac

Some software uses `audio/flac`. Some uses `audio/x-flac`.

MDN [suggests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Containers) that `x-flac` is "non-standard".  But based on what?

But [this appears to be the official registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#audio) for `audio/` types... and `audio/flac` doesn't appear on it.  Has nobody ever registered flac there? Whyever not?

In 2021, what is the correct place to determine the list of "standard" content-types, and what is it for FLAC?

Comment: I think MDN should probably mark _both_ of those as non-standard: you've found the official registry, and it's not on it, so there _is_ no standard value. I guess Xiph never asked for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this appears to be the official registry for audio/ types... and audio/flac doesn't appear on it. Has nobody ever registered flac there? Whyever not?

One cannot just register a media type. It can only be registered when an IETF document has need of it. A document describing the FLAC format has just been approved, so today, the audio/flac media type has been added to the registry.

So, from today, "audio/flac" is official, though many applications have been  using it for years already.

Answer (score 4):

In 2022 [Mozilla seems to have the answer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Containers#flac):

> The Free Lossless Audio Codec (FLAC) is a lossless audio codec; there
> is also an associated simple container format, also called FLAC, that
> can contain this audio. The format is not encumbered by any patents,
> so its use is safe from interference. FLAC files can only contain FLAC
> audio data.
>
> audio/flac
> audio/x-flac (non-standard)

So, depending on that I go with `audio/flac`. It seems to work for me on a Grav website.